# How to calculate system idle time out and put the machine to sleep?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there anything that provides a system-wide last user input information? We want to use C# to get the idle time for the system across all sessions and put the machine to sleep if nobody is using the machine for X minutes.

It appears that GetLastInputInfo is user specific. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Why not just let Windows do that itself?

Comment: It is supposed to be a solution that takes care of putting down the machines to sleep in case it is idle, regardless of the logged on user.

Comment: The system being idle is not the same as a user not interacting with the system. For instance, a system can be busy playing films or music.

Comment: Valid point. So, is there a "real good" way to figure out whether the system is idle?

Comment: Simon Mourier has a solution for that. I don't know if it's "really good enough" for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Windows [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and register a Task that's launched when the system is idle. That's the best way, as it's no so obvious to determine the idleness of a system (check out the article at least to get a grasp of what it means). You can also protect task using security, etc. See here for more information on this: [Task Idle Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383561%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

To program the task scheduler in C#, you can use various wrapper. Here is at least one: [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is outdated. Now those settings in Task Scheduler are defined as deprecated and they won'work.

Comment: @Grisha - Only some settings (Duration and WaitTimeout) are depracated, but the idle condition is still there.