# how to Run an winform application through window service when system goes idle

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

My aim is to create a login form where the login form comes when the system goes idle.This form contains username/ password and comment box where user have to provide reason for why system has goes to idle state.(ie if user left for a meeting or a break,he/she should provide details about it).this should be a window application which i managed to make.

Now i have to make this application run when ever system goes idle and the user can use only when login through this.So windows service is a option to run a program when the system starts and it can be managed well through service. So i made a window service which mange to run the application when the service start.

Now i have mange the window service to call this win app every time system goes idle. what possible ways can i make it work through window service.

I have already mention the above question in a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151011/how-to-run-an-net-application-when-system-becomes-idle)

please help...

Comment: So, you're saying yourself this question is a duplicate? Then you should edit your other question and/or add a bounty, not repost a new identical question... :\

Comment: Given your recent questions, I get the feeling you're trying to re-implement the Windows operating system, piece-by-piece. As I have previously suggested, you need to customize the login user interface (`msgina.dll`) if you want this kind of control. This is not what Windows Services are designed for. I'm not sure why you feel the built-in system security is inadequate, but if it is, patchwork solutions like this certainly aren't going to be any better.

Comment: @kappa: Yeah, but no one understood his previous question because 1) it was poorly explained, 2) it's a completely backwards approach to a simple problem. Posting a new one looks like a way to start over, unless the same users happen to read the new question, too. It also doesn't help much if you still explain things just as poorly.

Comment: As per your request i have edited the question hope you get the issue, what i am looking for.thanks for providing valuable comments please help with your ideas

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of app that users *hate* with a passion, nobody likes a machine forcing them to do things.  They'll try everything they can to get rid of it or sabotage it.  Any data it collects is junk.  Vista partly solved the problem, services cannot do this anymore.

Don't waste your time on it.

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. I wish I were brave enough to post answers like this, instead of hiding them in a comment.